# Como fazer insert no banco para formulários na mesma página?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou testando um form antes de colocar na produção, porque já temos um sistema que insere a movimentação de patrimônio 1 a 1 e estou querendo fazer com que o operador consiga fazer várias ao mesmo tempo, por exemplo, vai mover 5 impressoras pro mesmo lugar que ele não tenha que fazer o processo 5 vezes...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

então ele diz quantos produtos vai movimentar e clica em enviar e abre o número de formulários desejado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é : Como eu faço para que quando ele clique no primeiro botão gravar ele faça o update no banco sem sair da página e se não for pedir muito, aparecer uma mensagem de inserido no 'quadrado' que clicou em gravar porque quem vai operar isso, não tem muita facilidade com computadores. Segue o código.

```
    <?php


$produtos = $_POST['produtos']



?>

<?php

 for ($i=0; $i < $produtos; $i++) { 
   # code...
?>

    <div class="container">

  <br>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-9">

                    <form>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Patrimonio</label>
                            <input name="data[PessoaEmail][0][email_tipo_id]" required="required" id="PessoaEmail0EmailTipoId" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">

                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Teste</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data[PessoaEmail][0][email_tipo_id]" required="required" id="PessoaEmail0EmailTipoId" placeholder="teste">
                          </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Gravar</button>

                    </form>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">




            </div>

        </div>

  <br>
    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Pesquise sobre requisições assíncronas com JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Se seu problema for apenas quando clicar no botão enviar não quer que a pagina recarregue tu pode usar o Javascript o método [preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp), mas caso sua dúvida seja outra, tente deixar mais clara para que possamos te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

tira os campos de dentro do form e usa ajax para enviar os dados.

quando você tem um button type="submit" dentro de um form, sempre que o button type="submit" for acionado, ele vai atualizar a pagina e enviar os dados dos input dentro daquele form